# How to use Typeahead.js to get a set of data without filtering in any user input

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I want to get the local dataset with any user input. This is like user's history. For example any time that a user types something, I want to get the first 2 items of the array userHistory.

```
<div class="summary">
  <div class="trip">
    <input class="history-data tt-input" type="text" placeholder="Some text" />
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
   var $stateInput = $("input.history-data");


  function getData() {

    var userHistory =  [ { userHistory: 'History 1' }, { userHistory: 'History 2' }, { userHistory: 'History 3' }, { userHistory: 'History 4' } ];

    return userHistory;
  }

  $stateInput.typeahead(
    {
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'userHistory',
      limit: 2,
      source: getData,
    });

});
```

[Demo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thanassis05/2wdav5ka/1/)